# Javascript only Iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, global-variables, nw.js

I am making a nw.js application that I want to be able to be modded. However, for ease of use I want to allow all the mods to have their own separate sets of global variables, yet I still need to access all the variables and classes from the main application. My original idea was to use iframes, which would probably work. However, iframes are slow and are just simply messy code. Is there any better way to do this, or am I just stuck using iframes?

Answer (score 0):

Would creating a global object that represents the namespace for your module suffice?

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
```

It would be impossible to have two global namespaces within the same window as all global properties are properties of the window.

Comment: That would work, but I imagine that would put a lot of extra work on the modder, because they would have to type in that namespace every time they needed to access any global variables they created themselves. However, this is still a much nicer idea than my original, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the require function is the way to go. I got the idea while reading Brian's answer, so I thank Brian.